# Не отображается результат компиляции Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: Я уже все перепробовал, руки опускаются ,помогите]

Не понимаю ,почему не показывается скомпилированный код, хотя полмесяца назад все было норм, вроде ничего не трогал, очень прошу помощи

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно работает, ваша программа выводит на консоль 4 переноса строки.

первый внешний цикл вообще не запускается так так условие не соблюдено i=0, и i не больше > 4

второй внешний цикл запускается и выводит перенос строки (sout) на каждом цикле, второй внутренний цикл не запускается, так как j=0,  и j не больше > i+1

Comment: Да, я уже догадался но и вам огромное спасибо ,лучший